# exec sp_executesql in an IF stament and WHILE loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, while-loop

I'm having issues with my script where it will search all tables that contains 'Dummy' in table name. I have a SELECT query where the result will be the tables that is to be deleted.

```
    SELECT  Row_Number() Over (Order By name) As RowNum
                        , name
                FROM    sys.all_objects
                WHERE   type = 'U'
                        and name like '%Dummy%'
                        and schema_id = @schemaID
```

and it returned:

```
    RowNum  name

    1   Dummy

    2   DummyJoinTbl1

    3   DummyJoinTbl2

    4   DummyJoinTbl3
```

but when I execute the below script,

```
    DECLARE

    @schemaName nvarchar(100),
    @schemaID int,
    @tblName nvarchar(100) = '',
    @cnt int = 1,
    @rowNumber int = 1,
    @SQL nvarchar(100)

    SET @schemaName = (select SCHEMA_NAME()) -- this is dbo
    SET @schemaID = (select SCHEMA_ID()) -- this is 1

    BEGIN

    WHILE (@cnt > 0)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @tblName = +name
            FROM 
                (
                SELECT  Row_Number() Over (Order By name) As RowNum
                        , name
                FROM    sys.all_objects
                WHERE   type = 'U'
                        and name like '%Dummy%'
                        and schema_id = @schemaID
                ) ReferenceTable    
            WHERE RowNum = @rownumber

            SET @cnt = @@ROWCOUNT
            SET @rownumber = @rownumber + 1

            IF (@cnt > 0)
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'DROP TABLE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tblName + ' - RowCount:' + cast(@cnt as nvarchar(100))
                set @SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tblName
                exec sp_executesql @SQL

            END

        END

        PRINT 'DONE'

    END
```

the result it returned:

```
    DROP TABLE dbo.Dummy - RowCount:1
    DROP TABLE dbo.DummyJoinTbl2 - RowCount:1
    DONE
```

What could have be the reason why the other tables are missed? When I removed

```
    set @SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tblName
        exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

it will print all the tables.

```
    DROP TABLE dbo.Dummy - RowCount:1
    DROP TABLE dbo.DummyJoinTbl1 - RowCount:1
    DROP TABLE dbo.DummyJoinTbl2 - RowCount:1
    DROP TABLE dbo.DummyJoinTbl3 - RowCount:1
    DONE
```

Please do take note that the tables in the given are all empty. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you change `set @SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tblName` to `SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tblName`?

Comment: Still the same even if I used SELECT instead of SET

Comment: What about setting @SQL to a greater length than 100?  This seems like a truncation issue.

Comment: not really truncate issue as the characters expected are less than 100. I did try changing the length of @SQL from 100 to 1000 but still the same. I'm thinking it might go to performance issue. I don't have rights to alter the hardware or performance for that matter. I can only alter codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because after deleting first table result of select statement becomes to the next:

```
1   DummyJoinTbl1

2   DummyJoinTbl2

3   DummyJoinTbl3
```

It’s the reason of skipping of DummyJoinTbl1, because @rownumber = 2. Next loop @rownumber = 3 and it’s exceed number of records.
Do not use WHERE RowNum = @rownumber

Use SELECT TOP(1) @tblName = +name without nested select and ROW_NUMBER()

It's also better to use cursor with 1 select instead of selecting N times inside the WHILE statement

Comment: Darn, that PRINT got me confused lol. Your logic is correct. Appreciate the effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect place to use a cursor, if you do that you'll require a lot less code.  Here is a simplified sample, it assumes that you only want to delete tables from a single DB:

```
USE TempDB1;

CREATE TABLE test1 (i INT);
CREATE TABLE test2 (i INT);
CREATE TABLE test3 (i INT);
CREATE TABLE test4 (i INT);

DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(200),
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE c CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT  name
FROM    sys.all_objects
WHERE   type = 'U'
        AND name LIKE '%test%'
        AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID();

OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @tableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tableName;
    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @tableName;
END;

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

Comment: I reviewed the code and this seems to also work. I'm picking the other one as I'd like to stick to my code. I never tested this one though. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: do as you like, but this version is simpler and more efficient as it doesn't require the SELECT to be run multiple times.